# How get the value of selected text in a python event from an HTML widget in Project Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, widget, jupyter

I'm trying to get the value some text that I've hi-lighted with a mouse in [Jupyter Interactive HTML widget](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20List.html) in a python event and can't find an example of how to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: how about right click to open context menu and select `Copy` or use `Ctrl+C`?

Comment: Using the clipboard doesn't doesn't solve this issue since I don't have access to the clipboard in python  and even if I did I would lose the relative context of the hi-lighted text. I see that the original question was edited by a moderator that removed the detail about the needing to get the hi-lighted text in a python event. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think it would be easier to use `JavaScript` then Python for this - because JavaScript has access to all elements in web browser.